# sync framework microsoft encryption and compression

Tags: authentication, encryption, compression, microsoft-sync-framework

We have started prototyping with the sync framework...I would like to know if / how we can use encryption, authentication and compression...

Are we limited to using ssl in wcf or are there other possibilities...also would like to know if compression or authentication is possible and how? Any links with examples great...

I am presuming as its WCF based we can use all WCF authentication mechansims and maybe even a compression transport channel or such... but if there are examples floating around that I am too stupid to find please let me know...

Cheers alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For encryption you can use the WCF Binding tag

```
<security mode="Transport">
   <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
   <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```

For authentication you can ask on the Service class for the ServiceSecurityContext.Current. WindowsIdentity to know who is the user and do you authentication rutine.

For compression you can create you WCF Channel with can use the GZip compression before sending the data and uncompress before receiving. (I will upload an example today).

Also you can download an implementation of compression here: http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2006/03/29/WS_2D00_Compression-for-WCF.aspx

Comment: Hey wow! :-) Great answer! I will check it out, I won't give you full points just yet in case someone can top it but many thanks already and I reckon the points are yours! :-)